# Simplifying expressions with rational exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I only half understand this concept, the question is

Simplify $2(x^2+8)^{\frac85} + x \cdot 3(x^2 + 8)^{\frac35} \cdot 9x$

The steps I have so far are

$2(x^2+8)^{\frac85} + 27x^2(x^2 + 8)^{\frac35}$

$(x^2+8)^\frac35[$

After the bracket is where I'm stuck at conceptually. What am I doing with the $27x^2$ and the $2?$ Am I adding them together?

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: Yes, you add them together.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good with the formatting here hold on

Comment: $\frac{2(x^2+8)^8}{5}+\frac{3x(x^2+8)^3}{5}\cdot9x = \frac{(x^2+8)^8}{5}\cdot2+\frac{(x^2+8)^3}{5}\cdot27x^2 = \frac{(x^2+8)^8}{5}\cdot(2+27x^2) = \frac{(x^2+8)^8\cdot(2+27x^2)}{5}$

Comment: The formatting ruined it, the 3/5 and 8/5 are exponents to the (x^2 + 8) sorry

Comment: @user406105  One editor cleaned up the formats, but changed some of your numbers.  I have, (I hope) changed the numbers back to your original post.

Comment: It should be (x^2 + 8) with 3/5 and 8/5 being the exponent for the terms respectively.

Comment: You treat the term "$\frac{(x^2 + 8)}5$" as a unit item, and factor it just as you would a number or a variable.  For $2a + 3x*a*9x$ you would do $2a + 3x*a*9x = 2a + 27x^2*a = a[ 2 + 27x^2]$.  This is no different: $2\frac{(x^2 + 8)}5 + 3x*\frac{(x^2 + 8)}5*9x = 2\frac{(x^2 + 8)}5 + 27x^2*\frac{(x^2 + 8)}5 = \frac{(x^2 + 8)}5[ 2 + 27x^2]$

Comment: The formatting is now correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with $27x^2$ and $2$ just yet. You will keep them inside the brackets, along with some other stuff, as a result of factoring out $(x^2+8)^{\frac{3}{5}}$; you'll simplify the expression in the brackets after that.

Your main goal right now is to factor. Remember that factoring is effectively division (in each term). For example, if you factor $x^2$ out of $x^5$ you will be left with $x^3$, i.e. you would write $x^5=x^2\cdot x^3$. Why? Because $\displaystyle \frac{x^5}{x^2}=x^3$, giving you the remaining factor for $x^5=x^2\cdot(\text{?})$.

Same here. To factor $(x^2+8)^{\frac{3}{5}}$ out of $(x^2+8)^{\frac{8}{5}}$ means to divide:
$$\frac{(x^2+8)^{\frac{8}{5}}}{(x^2+8)^{\frac{3}{5}}}=(x^2+8)^{\frac{8}{5}-\frac{3}{5}}=(x^2+8)^1=x^2+8,$$
so your expression simplifies to
$$2(x^2+8)^{\frac{8}{5}} + 27x^2(x^2 + 8)^{\frac{3}{5}}=(x^2 + 8)^{\frac{3}{5}}\left[2(x^2+8)+27x^2\right].$$
I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: So from there, im hoping im correct here the next step would be        (x2+8)^(3/5)[2x^2+ 16 +27x^2]  ->                                                                                             (x2+8)^(3/5)[29x^2 + 16]   and from there im done correct?

Comment: @user406105: Yes, that's right!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking for help on a second problem

$28x^{\frac12}(x^2 + x) - 12x^{\frac32} - 20x^{\frac12}$

Now this has 3 terms if im not mistaken and we only did practice problems with 2 terms. How do I simplify these 3 terms easily, and how do i treat the fractional exponents being right next to the x and not with a parenthesis.

Comment: Same thing: factor $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ out of all three terms to get $x^{\frac{1}{2}}[\ldots-\ldots-\ldots]$. And use the same technique for each factoring.

Comment: $x^{\frac12}[28(x2+x)−12.. - 20]$         I believe this is correct, with the only thing me missing is what to do with the 12 as it has a 3/2 fraction, how does that work with the distribution?

Comment: Same thing: to factor out means to divide, so $x^{\frac{3}{2}}/x^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}=x^1=x$.